# How does Shopular able to have GPS tracking in background?

Tags: ios

and able to track when you get to a certain location? Is this not disallowed by Apple?

I thought your app can only run in the background for 10 minutes (under certain circumstances).

Comment: You can run in the background for 10 minutes under *all* circumstances.  You can only run *longer* under certain circumstances.  Don't get cute with it either though, every day I see a question like "Wahhh Apple rejected my app because I specified GPS background mode but didn't utilize it like I should"

Answer (score 0):

The app should exist in the background, and in .plist file You should add **location** under **UIBackgroundModes**